# Java - Change FileReader's file path

Tags: java, java-io

I'm trying to read a file using FileReader, but the file I'm trying to access is in a different directory than the running code. Is there any way to make FileReader read files in other directories?

If not, are there any alternative ways of reading files from different directories?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or a relative path containing some ../'s?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\test.txt"));
```

Comment: IMO just use a forward-slash.

Answer (score 0):

BufferedReader does not know anything about paths.

Code might look like:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FIleInputStream("/a/b/c"), "utf-8"));
```